# how to point domain to specific ip in profreehost

Tags: dns, ip

I got a free domain name from from profreehost website, Now I need to make that domain name point to an ip-address of a server where my sample website is running. So I can access that website by give this domain in browser. Can anyone tell me the steps to accomplish this?

i tried to find an option , but I can't.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the dns tag explains: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you manage the domain or are owner of the domain, which is not the case when you get a free domain allocated to you by "profreehost", you can only host the website on profreehost.